# Meaning of the name - sahiṣṇuḥ from Vishnu Sahasranama

Tags: mahabharata, vishnu, krishna, vishnu-sahasranama

In the Vishnu Sahasranama, There is a mention of the name - Sahiṣṇuḥ

> Sahiṣṇuḥ - He who can suffer patiently

I don't understand Vishnu being the ultimate, free from all bondades? Why will he have to suffer? The meaning was take from Wikipedia, If it isn't the real meaning, please provide the meaning and the explanation. Is this name mentioned in any other puranas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Commentary](https://www.sadagopan.org/pdfuploads/Bhagavad%20Guna%20Darpanam.pdf) by Sri Parasara Bhattar on Vishnu Sahasranamam

> 146. Sahiṣṇuḥ - He translates this as the ***One who forgives***
>
> Bhagavan Vishnu is  called **Sahiṣṇuḥ** because its his **nature**(denoted by suffix *"Ishnuch"*) **to forgive the innumerable sins of people when they become [well disposed](https://www.google.com/search?q=to%20be%20well-disposed%20towards&rlz=1C5CHFA_enIN980IN981&oq=to%20become%20well%20disposed&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0i22i30l2j0i390l4.7462j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) towards him**.All accumulated sins which have been committed before or are about to be committed later, all sins done consciously or unconsciously by all organs of sense at all times in all ways, sins committed by not following injunctions or doing acts forbidden by Sastras, sins common and uncommon, sins committed by abusing and insulting him and sins committed by his own devotees, all are forgiven and tolerated by the Lord.**To the Lord forgiving is like a natural quality just like coolness is a natural quality to moon and water.**

I found another beautiful [commentary](https://archive.org/details/sri-vishnusahasranama-bhasya-sangrahartha-t-s-raghavendran-10-volumes-smso-sabha-2001-2005/mode/2up) by Dvaita Scholar Sri T.S. Raghavendran which explains the name in the following manner:

> 149. Lord Vishnu is called **Sahiṣṇuḥ** because ***He tolerates the
>      offences committed by His devotees.***
>
> The amount of tolerance that Lord Vishnu has,
> nobody else can even think of this quality.This is because Vishnu alone has the capacity to do anything, not to do anything, to do anything in any different way.**Still Paramatma tolerates every offence** and does only according to Vedic mandates and injunctions.This is **to save the validity of the Vedas, because when the validity of the Vedas is protected then dharma and adharmas are saved in the Jagat and then only there
> will be a cultured society, peace,** etc., in the world.So
> Paramatma, although He is not bound to any rules and regulations, and is totally beyond and above them, still out of of tolerance does as per Vedic Vakyas. He is the best सहिष्णुः ॥

Comment: @Shashaank You can find the mentions of name Sahiṣṇuḥ in the following below links
https://www.sanskritdictionary.com/?q=sahi%E1%B9%A3%E1%B9%87u
https://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/sahishnu

Comment: Thank you @Ramachandra